# Single word for someone who likes to party

Tags: single-word-requests

What is one word that can be used to describe someone who likes to party and go to clubs?

Comment: Socialite. 'Party animal' is a single lexeme but two orthographic words. But it is in use nowadays.

Comment: This can probably be solved by using standard references. But, I've offered some bits of slang below that might be helpful.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to Edwin Ashworth's excellent suggestions of *socialite* and *party animal* I can make a few suggestions.

All of these uses are slang/idiomatic hence they might be readily available in a thesaurus or standard reference.

*Partier* (alternatively partyer) -  usually a negative connotation.

> He flunked out of college because he was too busy being a *partier* to study.

(*Note - the proper usage of this term is to describe a party attendee.  This usage is slangy.*)

*Clubber* - similar to partier.

> That girl is a real clubber!  I always see her stumbling home at dawn!

(*Note - the proper usage of this term is to describe someone wielding a club, typically to beat something like a baby seal to death.*)

Also, an old-fashioned term:  *Good Time Charlie*

I think this usage is quite antiquated, but it remains useful.

Answer (score 0):

The term "reveller" is perhaps the most appropriate.

Reveller: one who engages in revelry

revelry: joyful celebration that includes eating, drinking, singing, and dancing

I think much of the other proposed terms aren't really appropriate. For example, "Socialite" has several strong connotations of high social standing, and isn't necessarily about liking to party.

Answer (score 0):

Consider, ***man/woman-about-town***

> A person who goes to many popular parties, clubs, etc. [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/man%E2%80%93about%E2%80%93town)